# How to solve what appears to be a Suvat question without enough variables?

Tags: physics

So I had my FSMQ exam earlier this year. As a part of the curriculum for this exam we had to learn these rules of SUVAT:

$$v = u + at$$
$$s = ut + \frac{1}{2}at^2$$
$$v^2 = u^2 + 2as$$
$$s = \left( \frac{u + v}{2}\right) t$$
$$a = \frac{dv}{dt}$$
$$v=\frac{ds}{dt}$$
The issue is then when I came to the question, I didn't know how to apply these formula to get the answer, try as I might, there didn't seem to be a way, so I left the question and moved on.  However, I would like to know how I could have solved the question as my mum (aka my maths teacher) wasn't really sure and had her hands full teaching the year $10$ s. The question itself is phrased as follows:

> Two cars are initially at rest facing in the same direction on a
> straight road. Car $A$ is $100$m ahead of car $B$. The two cars start from
> rest at the same moment.  Car $A$ moves with a constant acceleration of
> $1.5$ m s$^{-2}$ and Car $B$ moves with a constant acceleration of $2$ m s$^{-2}$.  Find
>
> (I) the distance that car $B$ travels before it overtakes car $A$
>
> (II) the speed of car $B$ at the moment it overtakes car $A$

Maybe there are some other formula I didn't know about, but in my state of understanding I couldn't find the solution despite trying several of the SUVAT equations.

Comment: In questions like this it's important to have a clear picture of what's going on before you look at equations. Suppose car $B$ overtakes $A$ at time $T$, and that up to this time, it has traveled a distance $s_B$. Since the two cars have met at the time $T$, in the same time, $A$ must have traveled a distance of $s_A = s_B-100$. Next, for each car, you have an expression for how far it travels in time $T$ from the equations above $(2s_B^2 = 2T, 2s_A^2 = 1.5T)$. Now you have three equations and three unknowns, eliminate away.

Comment: @stochasticboy321 how did you get to the last equation in brackets? I can follow the rest of what your saying though :)

Comment: Those are the equation $s^2 = u^2 + at/2$ evaluated separately for cars $A$ and $B$ (note that $u_A = u_B = 0$, and $a_A = 1.5, a_B = 2$).

Comment: @stochasticboy321 I didn't know that one exists but I used$$ s = ut + \frac{1}{2}at^2$$ and that seems to have worked, don't know if I oversimplified somewhere because the answer numbers are surprisingly round ( I got 100m for the distance and 20m/s for the speed)

Comment: Oh, wait, this is my error. Those should be $s_A/s_B$ instead of $s_A^2 /s_B^2$. Apologies. Your method in the comment above is correct.

Comment: @stochasticboy321 thanks so much for the help, definitely wouldn't have gotten the answer on my own, had a little bit of a "duh that's how" moment though. Glad to finally have the question off of my chest, especially after getting my exam result this morning of an A, happy the missing 6 marks didn't drag me down :) if you could add an answer so I can close the question that would be appreciated,even if it's just a copy paste of the comment so I can accept it

Comment: Grand :). Another thing that might be helpful with these problems is to draw a figure. Things like $s_A = s_B -100$ tend to pop right out when you do that.

Comment: @stochasticboy321 I think I got $$sA = sB - 100$$ but I didn't know what to do with it once I had it, exam pressure makes people do silly things

Answer (score 0, accepted):

\begin{align*}
  s_A &= u_A t+\frac{1}{2}a_A t^2 \\
      &= 0(t)+\frac{1}{2}(1.5)t^2 \\
  s_B &= u_B t+\frac{1}{2}a_B t^2 \\
      &= 0(t)+\frac{1}{2}(2)t^2 \\
  s_B &= s_A + 100 \\
  t^2 &= 0.75t^2 + 100 \\
  t^2 &= 400 \\
  t   &= 20 \text{ s} \\
  v_B &= u_B+a_B t \\
      &= 2(20) \\
  &= 40 \text{ m s}^{-1}
\end{align*}